# Show that n points in the plane determine at most O(n$ ^{7/3}$) triangles that have a given fixed angle α.

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, euclidean-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry

I'd like to use the Szemerédi-Trotter theorem (for all m, n $\leq$ 1, we have that the number of point-line incidences in a set of n points and m lines in $\mathbb{R}$$^2$ is at most O(m$^{2/3}$n$^{2/3}$ + m + n)) to prove that n points in the plane determine at most O(n$ ^{7/3}$) triangles that have a given fixed angle α.

Does anyone have a proof?

Comment: do we have general position? otherwise I think this is false, consider the set with points $(0,0)$ along with  $(j,0)$ and $(0,j)$ for all $j\in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$. There are at least $n^2$ right triangles.

Comment: Yes, the points are in general position.

Comment: @jorge-fernández And what it the problem with $n^2$ triangles? $2<7/3$